# simple json parsing with asp Xtreme

Tags: json, asp-classic

Just confused with one little thing.

I am currently getting `{ "data": [ { "response": "true" } ] }` with the following code.

But I simple want to get `{ "response": "true" }`.

I tried every way I can but I kept failing.

I will appreciate a lot if you can help me with it.

```
            Set Dataset = JSON.parse("{ ""data"": [] }")        
            Set Record = JSON.parse("{}")
                Record.set "response", "true"
                Dataset.data.push(Record)
            Set Record = nothing

            Data = JSON.stringify(Dataset, null, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Set Record = JSON.parse("{}")
            Record.set "response", "true"
 Data = JSON.stringify(Record, null, 2)
```

I assume that JSONObject.data.push adds the record to an unnamed array.